# Rails Google Maps integration Javascript problem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, google-maps

**update I**

Based on feedback, I've changed var maps to var adds.

**problem description**

I'm working on Rails 3.0.0.beta2, following [Advanced Rails Recipes](http://pragprog.com/titles/fr_arr/advanced-rails-recipes) "Recipe #32, Mark locations on a Google Map" and I hit a road block: I do not see a google map. My @adds view uses @adds.to_json to connect the google maps api with my model. My database contains "latitude" "longitude", as floating points. And the entire project can be accessed at [github](http://github.com/fogonthedowns/Yardsign).

Can you see where I'm not connecting the to_json output with the javascript correctly? Can you see other glairing errors in my javascript? Thanks in advance!

My application.js file:

```
    function initialize() { 
      if (GBrowserIsCompatible() && typeof adds != 'undefined') {
        var adds = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13);
        map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());

        function createMarker(latlng, add) {
          var marker = new GMarker(latlng);
          var html="<strong>"+add.first_name+"</strong><br />"+add.address;
          GEvent.addListener(marker,"click", function() {
            map.openInfoWindowHtml(latlng, html);
          });
          return marker;
        }

        var bounds = new GLatLngBounds;
        for (var i = 0; i < adds.length; i++) {
          var latlng=new GLatLng(adds[i].latitude,adds[i].longitude)
          bounds.extend(latlng);
          map.addOverlay(createMarker(latlng, adds[i]));
        }
        map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter(),map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));
      }
    }  
    window.onload=initialize;
    window.onunload=GUnload;
```

Layouts/adds.html.erb:

```
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=true_or_false&amp;key=ABQIAAAAeH4ThRuftWNHlwYdvcK1QBTJQa0g3IQ9GZqIMmInSLzwtGDKaBQvZChl_y5OHf0juslJRNx7TbxK3Q" type="text/javascript"></script>

<% if @adds -%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var adds = <%= raw @adds.to_json %>;
</script>
<% end -%>
```

**Rails Console Output**

```
a = Add.all
 => [#<Add id: 1, first_name: "Jason", last_name: "Wade", address: "225 Anzavista Ave, San Francisco, CA", address2: "", zip: "94115", city: "San Francisco", phone: "415-280-6678", float: nil, campaign_id: 1, email: "jwade@gmail.com", employer: "Google", occupation: "", created_at: "2010-04-06 14:00:36", updated_at: "2010-04-06 14:00:36", latitude: 37.779623, longitude: -122.445662>] 

ruby-1.9.1-p378 > a.to_json
     => "[{\"address\":\"225 Anzavista Ave, San Francisco, CA\",\"address2\":\"\",\"campaign_id\":1,\"city\":\"San Francisco\",\"created_at\":\"2010-04-06T14:00:36Z\",\"email\":\"jwade@gmail.com\",\"employer\":\"Google\",\"first_name\":\"Jason\",\"float\":null,\"id\":1,\"last_name\":\"Wade\",\"latitude\":37.779623,\"longitude\":-122.445662,\"occupation\":\"\",\"phone\":\"415-280-6678\",\"updated_at\":\"2010-04-06T14:00:36Z\",\"zip\":\"94115\"}]"
```

Comment: Where are you assigning the javascript variable adds? I assume you're setting the rails instance variable @adds in a controller, but you only assign to the js variable maps. 

if (GBrowserIsCompatible() && typeof **adds** != 'undefined') {

Comment: Yeah, rename your `var maps` to `var adds`.

Comment: Noticed your edit, can you edit your question to show these changes. It's not really clear what your problem is, can you confirm that the typeof adds is undefined and initialisation is taking place?

Comment: Done. (changes reflected above) Also is there a simple "hello world" test I could do to verify that? I'm a rails developer :/ and have small exposure to javascript.

Comment: Hi. First off you need to change back "var adds = new GMap2(docu" to   "var map = new GMap2(docu". The easiest way to check this kind of thing is alerts. Put alert(adds) and alert(adds != 'undefined') after adds definition, in the inline javascript. Also put an alert in the intialise function, check it's working.

Comment: Okay, I see a "function initialize() {...." alert, an "[object Object]" alert, and "true". In order to output the html to_json command I added <%= raw @adds.to_json %>, and my html source looks different, than the object, Object output.

Comment: Just fyi, I made https://rubygems.org/gems/gmaps4rails which is a useful wrapper with several options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  var bounds = new GLatLngBounds;
```

should be

```
  var bounds = new GLatLngBounds();
```

And you were initially correct:

```
  var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
```